# Refresh UI after changing source code

Tags: unity, c#

I was trying following things.

GameManager :

```csharp
bool gameHasEnded = false;
public GameObject completeLevelUI;

public void CompleteLevel(){
    completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);    
}

public void EndGame(){
    if(gameHasEnded == false){
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Invoke("Restart",2f);
    }
}

void Restart(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

[image]

[image]

EndTrigger :

```csharp
public GameManager gameManager;

void OnTriggerEnter(){
    gameManager.CompleteLevel();
}
```

I get a log in the console "`END`". Earlier I was using `Console.Log("END");` on `CompleteLevel()`, but I changed that source code. The old code seems to be working and not the new one. It's like Unity couldn't refresh that source code. (And I am sure that I have successfully saved the `C#` file.)

````csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }

}
```
````

Comment: Hi there, silly question maybe, but since your old code code is still executed, but you made sure to save the C# file, did you restart the game by exiting play mode and re-entering it?

Comment: @D.Kallan Yes! I did. I tried twice times

Comment: What is calling `EndGame`? Something in your UI? Is your GameManager getting destroyed on Scene reload or is something resetting `gameHasEnded` back to true? Are you sure the `END` is not coming from a different script? Like the one that prints `ground`

Comment: @Zibelas Yes! You were right. When I double clicked the `END` log then, it returned me to `PlayerCollision`.

Comment: I had solved the problem another way. I added another source code to `PlayerCollision` if collisionInfo name is `END` than it will call an function from `GameManager` which is `CompleteLevel`. I solved the problem another way. But, I want to access `EndTrigger` without that source code. Why I am unable to access `EndTrigger`?

Comment: because it uses the wrong method `OnTriggerEnter()` is missing the parameter of the collision `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`. If is has not the parameter, Unity is not calling it on a collision since it can not magically know that it should use it for collision

Comment: @Zibelas Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As *Zibelas* said in the comments, you are using the incorrect method in `OnTriggerEnter()`. By not adding anything into the parentheses, the program doesn't know when it should activate the method, thus causing it not to do anything, because it isn't being called. In order to fix this, simply replace `OnTriggerEnter()` with `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`. This will tell it when to run the method.